# Spring security- org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains'

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Hi I am trying to implement spring security in my project by following this tutorial http://www.baeldung.com/2011/10/31/securing-a-restful-web-service-with-spring-security-3-1-part-3/#config, I am getting following exception while running my program-

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains':
>   Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: NULL  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:532)

my web.xml looks like-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

    <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

    <!-- Spring root -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>
         org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
      </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>org.baeldung.spring</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Spring child -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>api</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>api</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- <welcome-file-list> -->
    <!-- <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file> -->
    <!-- </welcome-file-list> -->

</web-app>
```

and my webSecurityConfig.xml looks like-

http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd">

```
<http use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="restAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <intercept-url pattern="/api/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />

    <sec:form-login authentication-success-handler-ref="mySuccessHandler" />

    <logout />
</http>

<beans:bean id="mySuccessHandler" class="org.baeldung.security.MySavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="temporary" password="temporary" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
            <user name="user" password="userPass" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

I know this is a possible duplicate of [org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11447534/org-springframework-beans-factory-beancreationexception-error-creating-bean-wit), but I have tried the solution with no avail which might be because I am still a novice in springs. Any help is highly appreciated.

I am loading websecurityconfig.xml from SecSecurityConfig.java in the org.baeldung.spring framework it looks like-

```
package org.baeldung.spring;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;

@Configuration
@ImportResource({ "classpath:webSecurityConfig.xml" })
@ComponentScan("org.baeldung.security")
public class SecSecurityConfig {

    public SecSecurityConfig() {
        super();
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show/post wher you are loading the webSecurityConfig.xml file? Judging by the current information it isn't being loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the stacktrace information it appears as if you have conflicting framework jars in your classpath. When using maven use `mvn dependency:tree` to figure out which dependencies get used, I suspect that there is an older spring-beans.jar in your classpath.