# Spring MVC database connection with Annotation

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am create Spring MVC database connection with Annotation. i got this error

> `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException`: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is `java.lang.NoSuchFieldError`: `USER_DECLARED_METHODS`

So any one please give idea about this?

Comment: I think it is dependency problem at least according by this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244183/upgrading-from-spring-3-0-3-release-results-in-java-lang-nosuchfielderror-user

Comment: please post the full stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

Check you have proper jars in your build path.

```
org.springframework.beans-.....jar
org.springframework.web.servlet-......jar
```

and other necessary **j2EE**, **Spring** jars.